# flutter SingleChildScrollView and Column position

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one problem.

My app is
`SingleChildScrollView -> column -> children: A,B(variable height),C`

I expcted

If A,B,C not overflow.
C position is bottom of screen.

If A,B,C overflow.
C position is tail of content.

but it's not work.

I can't use flexible, spacer..etc.. because SingleChildScrollView

How can do that?
[image]

Comment: Can you drop a picture or clip of what you want to do?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi okay, I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as an option

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(child: SomeWidget()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            height: 340,
            color: Colors.red[200],
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            height: 620,
            color: Colors.orange[200],
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              color: Colors.green[200],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]